# Target Creature description for Hallow/Unhallow

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

You can attach a spell to [Hallow](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/hallow.htm)/[Unhallow](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/unhallow.htm). In current spell's description, for the attached spell it reads as:

> You may designate whether the effect applies to all creatures, creatures that share your faith or alignment, or creatures that adhere to another faith or alignment

As being the DM of the group, I am wondering: Can I set the *target creatures* as *Anybody who do not worship Chemosh* or *creatures who are not Chaotic Evil*?

Since Hallow/Unhallow spells attached spell have a duration of 1 year, I am not sure it if is OK (and not very powerful) if I choose the target creature like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hallow/Unhallow  is not a spell that targets creatures and you don't get to choose who or what it targets. As part of the spell casting process, you follow the text and pick one of these literal phrases for what the attached spell will apply to:

- "all creatures"
- "creatures that share your faith or alignment"
- "creatures that adhere to another faith or alignment"

The spell doesn't say you get to pick something more specific that falls under one of those – you pick exactly one of those options and that's all the specificity you get.

So you can have it affect either all creatures, or creatures that match your faith or your alignment, or creatures that have a different faith or alignment than yours, nothing more detailed than that.

Comment: I notice my question was quite misleading, so I edited it. Yes, I am speaking about the attached spell, not the spell ıteslf. For me, related text is confusing because I can either evaluate that text as *creatures with the same faith or creatures tat do not belong to his faith* (as you mention above)  or *creatures with the same faith or creatures belong to another one faith within the phaneon (some other god, not all gods except caster clerics' god)*

Answer (score 6):

Those are both valid targets, as long as whoever cast the spell a) worships Chemosh (another faith) or b) is Chaotic Evil (another alignment).

I suppose a more complete wording may be:

> ...creatures that adhere to any other faith or alignment.

Comment: Good guess. Since Another might mean any other or a specific other, the key to the problem is that, if they wanted the spell to work on any single faith or alignment they could have written so. (This makes the spell extremely weak on the hands of PCs of different faith or alignment).